# What does a code pointer look like?

Tags: buffer-overflow

I'm writing a fictional short story in which I would like to be factually accurate. The protagonist is trying to overflow a buffer.

Suppose he is allowed to input a null-terminated string in a *really low-security app*. What would the payload of the string he uses look like? Would it just be a hex address? Would it differ for different computers? If possible, could you please give an example payload that would potentially work for a modern (post 2004) Windows or Mac laptop?

Comment: google "shellcode". And yes, it would be different between computer architectures (e.g. x86 for server/desktop/laptop and arm for phones).

Comment: The metasploit project or ExploitDB.com have numerous examples that you can use for your purpose.

Comment: Search buffer overflow attacks in youtube and there will be loads of videos.

Answer (score 1):

For being targeted;

- If you need a fancy source code (which is real) https://github.com/rapid7/meterpreter/blob/master/source/server/server_setup_win.c you can check this
- If you need a fancy shellcode (which is real) have a look https://github.com/jivoi/pentest/blob/master/exploit_win/ms08-067.py it will be at line 54
- the most well known vulnerability of post 2004 is MS08-067. You can see that exploitation steps at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joT8NxlXxVY.
- the most well known payload / backdoor is meterpreter.

PS. There is hundreds of exploits for post 2004, I just shared most known and nearest date.